# Get info.plist source tree path by reverse engineering

Tags: ios, xcode, reverse-engineering, ipa

I'm working on the iOS reverse engineering. I want to know if I can fetch the Info.plist file path (Source tree path, and not the path inside the ipa) from the ipa file.

Any help would be really helpful.

Comment: can you elaborate your needs ?

Comment: Basically, I want to know the source tree path of the info.plist by reverse engineering the ipa file. I'm doing the reverse engineering, but I don't know if this info is available anywhere inside the ipa/binary. I think it is not available. However, I want a confirmation.